# Virtual Environment Has Wrong Python Version

Tags: python, conda, version

I have to use some old code that depends on Python 2.7 but I use Python 3. To change Python versions, I created a virtual environment (specifying Python to be version 2) but my python version didn't seem to change.

Here's what I tried:

`conda create -n python_two_env python=2.7`

This created the environment, then I activated it using:

`conda activate python_two_env`

and checked the python version using:

`python --version`

I got:

`Python 3.10.10`

Why is the virtual environment's python version not 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, I found that the issue was in my `.bashrc` file. Specifically, I had defined the alias `python=python3` which was being prioritized over the virtual environment's python version. After commenting out that alias, `python --version` in the virtual environment returns `Python 2.7.18 :: Anaconda, Inc.`